# No of Passes in a Bubble Sort

Tags: iteration, bubble-sort

For the list of items in an array i.e. **{23 , 12, 8, 15, 21}**; the number of passes I could see is only 3 contrary to (n-1) passes for n elements. I also see that the (n-1) passes for n elements is also the worst case where all the elements are in descending order. So I have got 2 conclusions and I request you to let me know if my understanding is right wrt the conclusions.

**Conclusion 1**
(n-1) passes for n elements can occur in the following scenarios:

1. all elements in the array are in descending order which is the worst case
2. when it is not the best case(no of passes is 1 for a sorted array)

**Conclusion 2**
(n-1) passes for n elements is more like a theoretical concept and may not hold true in all cases as in this example **{23 , 12, 8, 15, 21}**. Here the number of passes are (n-2).

Comment: "contrary to (n-1) passes for n elements" Where did you read this from?

Answer (score 1):

In a classic, one-directional bubble sort, no element is moved more than one position to the “left” (to a smaller index) in a pass. Therefore you must make n-1 passes when (and only when) the smallest element is in the largest position. Example:

```
12 15 21 23  8  // initial array
12 15 21  8 23  // after pass 1
12 15  8 21 23  // after pass 2
12  8 15 21 23  // after pass 3
 8 12 15 21 23  // after pass 4
```

Let's define L(i) as the number of elements to the left of element i that are larger than element i.
The array is sorted when L(i) = 0 for all i.
A bubble sort pass decreases every non-zero L(i) by one.
Therefore the number of passes required  is max(L(0), L(1), ..., L(n-1)). In your example:

```
23 12  8 15 21  // elements
 0  1  2  1  1  // L(i) for each element
```

The max L(i) is L(2): the element at index 2 is 8 and there are two elements left of 8 that are larger than 8.

The bubble sort process for your example is

```
23 12  8 15 21  // initial array
12  8 15 21 23  // after pass 1
 8 12 15 21 23  // after pass 2
```

which takes max(L(i)) = L(2) = 2 passes.

For a detailed analysis of bubble sort, see [*The Art of Computer Programming* Volume 3: Sorting and Searching](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201896850) section 5.2.2. In the book, what I called the L(i) function is called the “inversion table” of the array.

Answer (score 0):

#### re: Conclusion 1

> all elements in the array are in descending order which is the worst case

Yep, this is when you'll have to do all `(n-1)` "passes".

> when it is not the best case (no of passes is 1 for a sorted array)

No. When you don't have the best-case, you'll have more than 1 passes. So long as it's not fully sorted, you'll need less than `(n-1)` passes. So it's somewhere in between

## re: Conclusion 2

There's nothing theoretical about it at all. You provide an example of a middle-ground case (not fully reversed, but not fully sorted either), and you end up needing a middle-ground number of passes through it. What's theoretical about it?

Comment: (12 15 21 23 8) takes 4 passes, yet is not in descending order.

Comment: ‘each element "moves" closer to its final position at a rate of 1 swap per pass’ is incorrect. After the first pass, the largest element is guaranteed to be at its correct position (the last position in the array), regardless of where it started.

Comment: @robmayoff Oh true, because one element would keep getting swapped multiples in one pass... Hmm is there a way to predict the number of swaps then?

Comment: I believe the number of swaps performed is sum(L(i)) for the definition of L given in my answer.

Comment: I think it's `max(L(i))` (which matches what you have in your answer, but not the comment here), but that makes sense. It's similar to what I was thinking. I think I made a mistake by dropping the sign from my "distance" column. I should have been paying attention only to the left-movers

Comment: max(L(i)) is the number of passes. Each pass may make many swaps.